# Discovering the IP of my NAS which is connected by Ethernet Cable

Tags: networking, server, mount, nas

So I've been unable to find the IP of the QNAP NAS that I am trying to use. I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 and have the NAS connected through an ethernet cable which goes directly from the NAS into my PC. One of the main problems is that I am a college student and using the school's internet, meaning I do not have a router that I can plug the PC and NAS into. I'm hoping to find a way to connect to the NAS directly through the ethernet cable between it and my PC, but cannot do so without knowing the IP, which again, thus far I have been unable to find. A program called Qfinder is the suggested way of finding the IP but I have been unable to get it to run on Ubuntu 16.10. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the NAS isn't connected to the LAN, unless you have bridging set up on the PC. Why don't you access it via USB? Or install your own router, not connected to the WAN?

Comment: Type `ifconfig -a` Does that interface have an IP address? Type `arp -an`.

Comment: 16.10 is End of Life as of July 20, 2017.  You should upgrade to a newer version ASAP.

Comment: I haven't tried connecting it through USB to the PC, I've only connected it by using an Ethernet cable from the NAS to the PC.

Comment: Is your question title incorrect? It seems that the NAS is NOT connected to the LAN.

Comment: You're right, sorry I wasn't paying attention to what I was saying. Yeah it's not connected, it's only connected through an ethernet cable. I edited the post accordingly.